# Append transform to already existing one

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I've defined an animation that uses `transform`.

I want to append additional `transform` to an already existing one using javascript.

Unfortunately when I try to append additional `transform` ,  my new one is ignored.

```js
var brick = document.getElementById('brick');

brick.style.transform = "rotateX(50deg)";
```

```css
@keyframes red {
  from {transform: translateY(10px);}
  to {transform: translateY(0px);}
}

#brick {
  animation: 1s red infinite;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="brick">
</div>
```

Comment: That's standard behaviour *for now*. You would need to restate the original transform in conjunction with the new one.

Comment: Whats the original transform in case where I have an animation? How can I figure out the current transform value?

Comment: See, there's the issue. Better to do the whole thing by j

Comment: Or use 2 nested divs

Comment: @vals In the end I did that :) Thanks.